# Do we have a term that is a combination of "sitting / standing side by side" and "sitting / standing back to back"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

> if two people **[stand or sit back to back](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/back_1#back_idmg_4)**, they stand or sit
>   with their backs facing or touching each other
>
> The children sat back to back so they couldn't see each others'
>   drawings.

---

> **[side by side](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/side_1#side_idmg_15)** ​close together and facing in the same direction
>
> There were two children ahead, walking side by side.
>
> The two sat side by side on the bench.

---

Eg: The couple is sitting back to back

[image]

Eg: The couple is sitting side by side

[image]

Now 2 people are facing 2 opposite directions and the left side of the woman may close to the left side of the man as the below picture

[image]

**How to express it?**

Comment: There probably isn't a native English term. That'll be why we use the French ***tête-à-tête*** to describe both the seating position and the actual ***seat design*** of those [S-shaped jobbies with a serpentine form](https://www.houzz.com/magazine/must-know-furniture-face-off-with-the-iconic-tete-a-tete-stsetivw-vs~33774424) that encourage two people to face each other and engage in conversation.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, I can see the chair, I often see it in some Spy movies, probably 2 people sit like that while having a secret conversation

Comment: I think that's probably because it's easier for the movie director to arrange the scene. In real life you'd probably go somewhere more private, 'cos those chairs are usually only used when there are many other people around (at a party), so the conversants can both "people watch" or strike up conversation with others if they get bored talking to each other.